# Computing estimates for segments of a sample

Tags: sampling, stratification

Suppose I want to estimate the average body weight of people in a population. I use a stratified sample of 50% men and 50% women and compute the desired metric.

Next, I want to compute the average body weight of people with brown eyes. Is there a way to "re-use" the first sample? Would computing the average body weight of people with brown eyes in the the initial stratified sample be valid?